# How to prevent android system to create notification from system tray?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am using GCM push notification in my app. I am using WakeFulBroadCastReceiver and invoking service to create notification.
1. If app is in foreground, code is working properly.
2. If app is in background. Android system creates another notification, without icon. I am getting my custom created notification too. So there are total two notifications.
 Here is my code in onReceive method of broadcastreceiver:

```
ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
ListenPushMessage.class.getName());
startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
```

Its working perfectly fine when app is in foreground. When app is in background,  its creating two notifications, one from my code, other one from system tray. I want to prevent that notification which is created by system.

Comment: "one from my code, other one from system tray" -- most likely, both are from your code, directly (e.g., you are using `NotificationManager`) or indirectly (e.g., you are using `startForeground()`).

Comment: but its creating notification even if I am not using NotificationManager

Comment: That just means that something else that you are doing is using `NotificationManager`. For example, calling `startForeground()` displays a `Notification`, even though you are not directly using `NotificationManager`.

Comment: I am not using startForeground()

Comment: Even though I am leaving onReceive() method empty.

Answer (score 0):

I know its quite late to answer but remove `notification` object from push at back-end; instead of `notification` use `data` object for `body,title`.
and create the notification using `data`.

something like:

```
{"to": "c4dgGSdnkWI:APA91bE_hQQTZ1NJo2nff4Sci7Cx2kNE64ReH1kQYxc01uttlOrdZetEFrcziBDwKVdfFiTh3BHVCeU2xl1KJv7VoG_eALgiHySIH-aF96Lhzh5eNSIbT_Cb_edE1g-kd-SeS8T8zfNL","data": {
"title": "data title",
"body": "data body",
"key": "Value"  }}
```